# Why isn't Entity Framework updating the child object here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a `Customer` model with a `MailingAddress` property - this is a navigation property to an `Address` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I have a form that posts a viewmodel back which contains a `customer`, along with the mailing address. Here is the save method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(CustomerFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }

    if (viewModel.Customer.Id == 0)
    {
        _context.Customers.Add(viewModel.Customer);
    }
    else
    {
        var customerInDb = _context.Customers
            .Single(c => c.Id == viewModel.Customer.Id);

        _context.Entry(customerInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel.Customer);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
}
```

When posting a new customer, everything works fine (mostly, see note below) and the customer is created along with a corresponding address record. However, when I edit an existing entry, the customer is updated but the address is not. I verified the updated address is being passed in the customer object. If I add a line like this:

```
_context.Entry(customerInDb.MailingAddress).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel.Customer.MailingAddress);
```

Then it is updated.

Is the child here still considered a detached entity? I assumed since it is a property of the `Customer` I am fetching it would be automatically saved with the parent. Why does this work with a new record and not with an update?

One note about the new record creation - a `Customer` record is created and has a `MailingAddress_Id` pointing to the address. The `Address` record is also created, but its `Customer_Id` is null...an idea why EF is not adding the key on that side of the relationship? Address model and view model code in case it helps:

```
public class Address
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    // Snip a bunch of address data properties     

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerFormViewModel
{
    // Snip irrelevant properties
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if your `Customer` and `Address` are in *one-to-one* relationship, then no foreign key is needed. Actually, in *one-to-one* relatioonships primary key on *dependant* side of relationship is also foreign key to *principal* side. Secondly, when you create new `Customer` you use `context.Customers.Add(viewModel.Customer);` and it adds model with all of its child models, but when you try to update using `_context.Entry(customerInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel.Customer);` it does not add all child navigation properties, to do so, you have to tell it to EntityFramework explicitly:

```
var customerInDb = _context.Customers
            .Single(c => c.Id == viewModel.Customer.Id);
_context.Entry(customerInDb)
    .CurrentValues
    .SetValues(viewModel.Customer);

var mailingAddressInDb = _context.Addresses
            .Single(m => m.Id = viewModel.Customer.MailingAddress.Id);
_context.Entry(mailingAddressInDb)
    .CurrentValues
    .SetValues(viewModel.Customer.MailingAddress);
```

It should work for you. But it is a bit awkward. When you have dozens of models, you would not even want to imagine it.

### Good news

The good news is that, there is an API to solve this problem from its roots. Your problem will be solved in just a few steps. You install it from NuGet using `Install-Package Ma.EntityFramework.GraphManager`, configure your models to meet [prerequisites](https://github.com/MammadovAdil/EntityFramework.GraphManager#prerequisite) (which are so easy) and handle whole graph using single line of code:

```
public ActionResult Save(CustomerFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }

    // Define state of whole graph with single line
    _context.AddOrUpdate(viewModel.Customer);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
}
```

Please, have a look at [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1153391/Automatic-graph-operations-using-EntityFramework) for a quick wallktrough. It has example code, so you can download and examine it. I am the owner of this API and I am ready to answer to your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the informative post. Question - say I added another address in the customer model -- for example, LegalAddress. Is this still considered a one-to-one relationship? If I did want to add a second address to the Customer model, is it better to just add the appropriate property or should I convert the relationship to one-to-many and use a collection of addresses in the Customer model, perhaps adding a property to Address to be able to tell them apart (Address.Type = MailingAddress or LegalAddress)?

Comment: @Jim, If you have two Address properties you should make it *one-to-many* relationship between them